# NetworkManager is supossed to create a file everytime it connects to a wireless connection?

Tags: networking, services, ip, configuration-management

Here is the NetworkManager.conf

```
NetworkManager.conf 
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile

[ifupdown]
managed=false

[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

My question is why the constant reconnection to wireless connections that I didn't make the connection.

```
jose@Safra:~$ journalctl -r -n 10 | grep NetworkManager
May 20 09:40:38 Safra NetworkManager[21256]: <info>  [1621514438.4023] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
May 20 09:40:38 Safra NetworkManager[21256]: <info>  [1621514438.3989] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: 4-way handshake -> completed
May 20 09:40:38 Safra NetworkManager[21256]: <info>  [1621514438.3450] device (p2p-dev-wlo1): supplicant management interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
May 20 09:40:38 Safra NetworkManager[21256]: <info>  [1621514438.3450] device (wlo1): supplicant interface state: associated -> 4-way handshake
```

Comment: I add some details.

Answer (score 0):

Network Manager creates a file every time there is a successful connection. The details are saved  in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`

As an example, your file may contain an entry like `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/preto_router.nmconnection`

If you have set Network Manager to connect automatically, then when your computer is booted or when airplane mode is turned off, when the wireless device scans and sees an access point whose SSID, as well as the MAC address, password, etc., are stored in system-connections and when ‘Connect automatically’ is set, then the wireless device does just that: connect automatically.